# What is the plural of platinum?

Tags: irregular-plurals

In the card game Dominion, I always thought that the “Platinum” card, in the plural form, would be “Platinums”. However, [Dominion Online](https://dominion.games/) lists the plural form as “Platina”.

Is this correct, or is Dominion Online wrong?

Comment: Do dictionaries (eg [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/platinum)) have anything to say on the matter? If they don't list _any_ plural form, what does this suggest? // What if 'platina' had another related meaning ([Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/platina)? Would this make the whimsical plural more or less acceptable?

Comment: The plural of several metals refers to common *objects* made from those metals. For example **irons**, **coppers**, **leads**, but I don't know of **silvers**, **golds**, etc unless it refers to *colours*.

Comment: Given that the card is a proper noun in the game, presumably they can make it plural however they like.

Comment: Whatever the game wishes, but hardly a concern of this site. In English platinum is a metal and uncountable. I would say “platinum cards”, but then, I would, wouldn’t I?

Comment: *Platinumerous*, obviously.

Comment: Wise people wishing to avoid pedantry and pedants will buy two “sets of Platinum” for their two cousins or be delighted to have been dealt “two Platinum cards.”.  But the automatic observation of Latin or Greek plural forms is dying out, except where they are already embedded, as with ‘data’.  Even here, few people speak of ‘a datum (singular).  ‘Animal’ is originally Latin word, but nobody would think of asking “What are those animalia on that hill over there?”.

Comment: In *Platinum card*, platinum is an adjective, therefore it has no plural. It's only the noun (card) that becomes plural: *Platinum* ***cards***. If the card is made *of platinum* (noun), then there is no plural form—it's a noncount noun. (As per the accepted answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [The Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese-italiano/platinum) the plural form is the same as the singular one:

***platinum***
noun ***(no plural )***

> a silver-coloured metal that is very valuable

[Plata](https://www.yourdictionary.com/platinum)  is the Spanish form from which platinum derives:

Origin of platinum

> Modern Latin from Spanish platina, diminutive of plata, silver from Prov, metal plate, silver bar, silver from Vulgar Latin an unverified form plattus, flat.

(Yourdictionary.com)

The plural form for the game is “platinum cards”:

> ***[Platinum](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Platinum#English_versions)*** is a basic Treasure card from Prosperity. It and Colony may be added to the supply in games using Kingdom cards from Prosperity. ***The Platinum pile contains 12 cards.***

Comment: ................. LMGTFY

Comment: @EdwinAshworth .......FBVRC.

Comment: 'No plural' is very different from ' the plural form is the same as the singular one'. 'Clothing' has no plural form. 'Sheep' covers both the singular and the plural form.